# Como puedo hacer que los items de un spinner ocupe mas, que no aparezcan puntos suspensivos?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

Al cargar los item del Spinner solo me ocupa una linea, he probado con android:singleline="false" y tampoco funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve y la intención es que el texto se ponga en las líneas que necesite:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues si le estás dando un tamaño fijo en el ancho en el xml, obviamente no va a pasar de ahí. Tendrás que hacerlo en función del contenido, pero claro, todo dependerá de donde lo tengas incluido.

Comment: La intencion es que se ponga en varias lineas pero no encuentro como

Comment: Me temo que eso no se puede hacer salvo que hagas personalizado el spinner, personalizando cada elemento para que sea un texto multiline, añadir separadores entre líneas, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D